# Best way to share data among two fragments implementing a map view?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, kotlin

Newbie to Android and I have some questions about fragments/livedata/viewmodels. My app (that deals with allowing users to create local tours) currently has a bottom navigation bar and each tab brings you to a new activity, the starting fragment being the home fragment. In that fragment, it has half a google map view that zooms in on the current location of the user, and half a list view where it will list tours in the area. I also have a search fragment, where I want a map in the background and a search bar on top.

What is the best way to share location updates between these two fragments? It looks [a lot like this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/arkilis/7aef93cd50cf372d3a7c3ed5391e8fbf/raw/bac9740b067e5dc143686f0aedd7de4767d20335/get_google_map.kt), where the location listener/map updates are contained in the home fragment. How do I make this accessible within the search fragment? I'm a bit confused on a) if that is possible and b) where that would be contained as I'm still trying to wrap my head around viewmodels/livedata/sharing data between fragments.

Comment: https://androidwave.com/passing-data-between-fragments/

Comment: Thanks! I've read through a lot of those articles, I'm just trying to check that in my particular situation what I should be using because it's a little unclear. How best should I be sharing location data that gets updated regularly between fragments?